# What causes tmux search to be case insensitive or casesensitive?

Tags: tmux, case-sensitivity

When I run a search in the copy paste mode of `tmux` sometimes it's case insensitive and other times it isn't.

I think I know what I do, but I don't understand what causes the search to be case-insensitive or case-sensitive.

I press CTRL+B,[ and then CTRL+s.

And sometimes the search is case sensitive and other times it isn't.

It's possible I'm not doing what I think I'm doing.  What causes this?

Comment: Is it SHIFT?  It feels like it's CTRL+SHIFT+S makes it case sensitive.

Comment: I guess the search is case-insensitive, unless there is a capital letter in the string you search for. Not an answer because it's just my quick observation that may be wrong.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I hope that's not the case...seems like a buggy sort of a thing.